# Can a sequence of "non-exploding" functions converging to zero have integrals not converging to zero?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

Maths student here just starting a second analysis course, with this problem that is supposed to be solvable by elementary methods (i.e. no high-powered theorems). However, our teacher is also having trouble with it. Part a) is easy, but part b) is not.

a) Construct a sequence $(f_n)$ of continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$ converging pointwise to the zero function but with $\int_0^1f_n(x)dx \nrightarrow 0$.

b) Is it possible to find such a sequence with $|f_n(x)|\le 1$ for all x and for all n?

For part a, there is an easy solution: [Show convergence of a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ to a continuous function $f$ does not imply convergence of corresponding integrals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508243/show-convergence-of-a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-f-n-to-a-continuous-fun)
and even an infinitely differentiable one: [Explicit sequence of polynomials which converge to zero but have non-zero integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585107/explicit-sequence-of-polynomials-which-converge-to-zero-but-have-non-zero-integr)

Any idea how to do part b? Thank you!

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860458/riemann-integral-of-sequence-of-uniformly-bounded-functions).

Comment: Thank you David Mitra. This completely solves the problem.